# Get symbol name

Tags: javascript, symbols

How the symbol name can be get in form of string from value of type `symbol`? [`Symbol.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toString) returns the name wrapped. E.g.

```
Symbol.iterator.toString()
// "Symbol(Symbol.iterator)"

Symbol('foo').toString()
// "Symbol(foo)"
```

Is there more direct way than parsing output of `toString()` method? For value `Symbol('foo')` I'd like to get just string `foo`.

Comment: Calling `toString` on it works fine and is quite straightforward. Why do you want something even more direct? I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Symbol.prototype.description`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/description) property:

```js
console.log(Symbol('foo').description)

console.log(Symbol.iterator.description)
```